# Making CLM Files in DIVA-GIS

Tags: climate, diva-gis

I'm downscaling some climate data for a small area in Italy, and have created the 36 monthly files for Tmin, Tmax and Prec. Having exported from ArcGIS 10.4 into ascii format (integers), then imported in DIVA-GIS 7.5 with no problems, the creation of the CLM file is hitting a snag. I'm getting the error message "attempting to read beyond end of grid file", then the module fails with an access violation.

I've tried running the program as Administrator to get around any potential read/write issues. I've previously successfully created CLM files with 30 arc second WorldClim data. Has anyone encountered this before?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Turns out the problem was down to some iffy projection. One set of variables had somehow been projected as UTM 32N instead of UTM 33N, so the inputs for CLM were not sharing the correct geographic space. The offending variables were reprojected and have successfully made the climate database.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a R package which helps streamline preparing climate data for use in DIVA GIS.

Instructions available on the [prepCLMdata GitHub page](https://github.com/DrKrisChan/prepclmdata)